# iterate the elements of cell array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I got this cell array resulted from the function textscan

r =

```
{139952x1 cell}
```

and when you type r{1} in the command window, you get something like

- '1:07:50'
- '1:07:50'
- '1:07:50'
- '1:07:50'
- '1:07:52'
- '1:07:52'
- '1:07:52'
- '1:07:52'
- '1:07:54'

my question is, how to reach an individual element in this cell array, the fourth element for example ?

Comment: `r{i}` should let you access the element `i` of a cell array. I looks like the contents of the cell might be an array. Try `a = r{1}` and examining `a` specifically.

Comment: no it doesn't  @eigenchris, this will display the whole column

Comment: I was trying to say that `r{1}` itself is a column array. So with `a=r{1}`, `a(4)` would be the 4th element of the array in the first cell of `r`.

Comment: @eigenchris I got you, thanks : ) yeah that works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is how to access parts of cells](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/multilevel-indexing-to-access-parts-of-cells.html) 
Basically you should do:

```
r{1}(i)
```

where i is a specified individual element

Comment: Yep indeed it takes some time ;) Once you done you can accept an answer clicking on it! Cheers!